# Wireless Extender cutting out

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

So I bought a wireless extender costing around £27 each. I have two in the house because we have thick walls and quite a large distance between the router and certain rooms. The wireless extenders seem to cut out regularly for roughly 10 - 30 seconds.

I thought maybe that the wireless extenders were conflicting, so I tried one extender and I have the same problem. Could anyone tell me: 
1) Is it more likely to be the extenders conflicting, a setting in my router or dodgy extenders and I should pay for a better one 
 
2) Whats the best method to extend my wireless, I don't have the option to setup another wired connection. I know that extenders slow it down normally by half but its the easiest to setup. I have a 25mbps connection, and with the extenders I get the best part of 7 mbps.. All I'm looking for is to get 5+mbps successfully around the house. Is there any industrial high strength methods that are over the top? If so that is ideal.

Just another thing, we are a family of 5 with at least 3 devices connected, not ideal but it's not likely to be avoided! So need something quite powerful - your thoughts are much appreciated.

I'm looking for a solution under £100. Thanks

Comment: not what you asked for, but with a ladder, drill & some silicone sealer, you could run cable outside the house [assuming you don't live on the 14th floor ;) You could even do what the SkyTV installers do & throw a cable over the roof. When I set up our house for wifi, I started with the idea of extenders, but ended up with wired access points. Been no trouble since.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's tough to say if you're having a range issue or a channel crowding issue.

I don't know how regulations work in the UK, but in the US wireless routers come in two frequency ranges; 2.4GHz and 5GHz.  The 2.4GHz frequency is unlincensed, so practically everybody uses it.  In a crowded neighborhood with lots of WiFi stations, the 2.4GHz spectrum can become quite crowded, leading to a situation where your computer says the signal is good but you still can't connect (or the speed is garbage despite the link speed being reported).

The 5GHz band, however, requires a license and so only the higher-end routers support it.  But because they cost more, fewer people have them and the 5GHz band is almost always wide open wherever you go.

If dual-band routers are a thing in the UK, I would recommend using the less-used band if you can.  Note that higher frequencies have a shorter range, so if you actually are having a range issue, this would make it worse, not better.

One more thing I could suggest...  If your wireless router has antennas that can be unscrewed from the back, try investing in some high-gain antennas. The connectors are standard and you can buy them online.  You'd need to buy three sets though; one for each of the extenders and one for the router itself.